# VSC: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Python Path case

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, errno

First, I will start by describing how the process was carried out:

1. I've added a folder to **Workspace** and I've received this when I want to execute code:

```
PS C:\Users\mikol\Desktop> cd "c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/Skonczone_rzeczy/Python_Bill_Lubanovic/Rozdzia 05"
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\mikol\Desktop\Skonczone_rzeczy\Python_Bill_Lubanovic\Rozdzia 05' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/Skonczone_rzeczy/Python_Bill_Lubanovic/Roz ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mikol\...ovic\Rozdzia 05:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
 
PS C:\Users\mikol\Desktop> & c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/Skonczone_rzeczy/venv/Scripts/python.exe "c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/Skonczone_rzeczy/Python_Bill_Lubanovic/Rozdzia 05/quiz.py"
C:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\mikol\\Desktop\\Skonczone_rzeczy\\Python_Bill_Lubanovic\\Rozdzia 05\\quiz.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

1.1. In that case I've executed this code:

```
pytania = [
    "Jaki kraj ma najwięcej jezior na świecie?",
    "Jaki kraj wytwarza najwięcej tlenu?",
    "Jaki kraj produkuje najwięcej energii elektrycznej ze źródeł odnawialnych?"]
odpowiedzi = [
    "Rosja", "Kanada", "Norwegia"
]
p_o = ( (0, 1), (1,2), (2, 0) )
for p, o in p_o:
    print("Pyt.:", pytania[p])
    print("Odp.:", odpowiedzi[o])
    print()
```

2. Then I wanted to check where the error was and created a regular Python file on the desktop and executed it in VSC and that working correctly!

```
PS C:\Users\mikol\Desktop\Skonczone_rzeczy> cd c:/Users/mikol/Desktop
PS C:\Users\mikol\Desktop> & c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/Skonczone_rzeczy/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/mikol/Desktop/test1.py
tell me sth: hello
hello
PS C:\Users\mikol\Desktop>
```

2.1. In this case I've used this code:

```
tell_me = input("tell me sth: ")
print(tell_me)
```

My VSC Workspace structure:
[The structure of this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ItC.png)

I've set up Python Path and created a virtual environment, also I've tried change those settings:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true
```

Moreover I've try change that:

[VSC environment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYZv3.png)

This folder consists of a lot of subfolders and every Python code cannot be executed because an error appears like the one above.

And now I have no idea what I've could miss.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Polish characters from paths should resolve the issue.